# How to cast object to int through method?

Tags: java, object, casting, int

```
public static int toInt(Object a)
{
    return (int) a;
}

public static Object tInput()
{
    return read.nextLine();
}
```

When I try

```
public static void main (String []args)
{
     System.out.println( toInt(tInput()) );
}
```

I get a class cast exception -- Even though I enter in numbers!!! ints!

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. can anyone help?

====EDIT====
People are saying I can't cast it because it's a string.
I tried this other method, and this works.
Can someone explain?

```
public static void check()
{
    Object h = 2014;
    int a = (int) h;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: What is `read` and what does `nextLine` return?

Comment: The reason the code in your edit works is because the runtime type of the object stored in `h` is `int`. The reference you use to refer to it, `h`, is a reference that can contain any `Object`. Since you assign it an `int` value then you can cast it to an `int` no problem because you're casting an `int` to an `int`. If instead you do `Object h = "Hi mom!"; int a = (int) h;` then you'll get a class cast exception because you're trying to cast a `String` to an `int`.

Comment: There is no common method for "casting" an arbitrary object to `int`.  A "cast" operation asserts that the referenced variable is of the type being cast to, or (in the case of primitives only) can be converted to that type with well-defined techniques.  What you apparently want to do is to convert a String to int.  In that case declare the parameter to be String and use Integer.parseInt.  Declaring the parameter as Object merely delays until run time an error that could be detected at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int toInt(Object obj)
{
      return Integer.parseInt((String) obj);
}



public static void main (String []args)
{
     System.out.println( toInt(tInput()) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
read.nextLine(); //returns a string.
```

You cant cast a string to an integer, so I would use the `Integer.parseInt(str)` to first parse the string into an integer, then cast. Try changing your tInput() method to the method below

```
public static Object tInput()
{
    return Integer.parseInt(read.nextLine());
}
```

Take a look at the Java Doc for Integer.parseInt(String) if needed

[Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

`Strings` are not `Integers` (and especially not `ints`). You can't cast them, you need to convert. A `String` can be converted into an int by `Integer.parseInt(myString)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast `String` to `int`.

Try this:

```
int myInt = Integer.valueOf(tInput().toString());
return myInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object is a String like in this case you can use:

```
    int i = Integer.valueOf((String) object);
```

If your object is an Integer you can case it:

```
   int i = (Integer) object;
```

Either method has risk of exceptions, so you will need to handle accordingly.